# Get distinct value from a list of T-SQL parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am using a tool to produce SQL queries and I need to filter one of the queries with a multiple parameters.

The query is similar to this:

```
Select * 
From Products
Where (@ProductTypeIds is null or Product.ProductTypeId in (@ProductTypeIds))
```

<sub>I know the above query is not correct on a traditional SQL, read on..</sub>

Essentially, I'm trying to apply a filter where if nothing is passed for `@ProductTypeIds` parameter, the where condition is not applied.

When multiple parameters are being passed, though, `@ProductTypeIds` is being translated by the tool into the following query:

```
Select * 
From Products
Where (@ProductTypeIds1, @ProductTypeIds2  is null or Product.ProductTypeId in (@ProductTypeIds1, @ProductTypeIds2))
```

Which is clearly an invalid query. So I thought I could be clever and use `COALESCE` to check if they are null:

```
Select * 
From Products
Where (COALESCE(@ProductTypeIds, null) is null or Product.ProductTypeId in (@ProductTypeIds))
```

This query is being translated correctly, however, now my use of `COALESCE` throws an error:

> At least one of the arguments to COALESCE must be an expression that is not the NULL constant.

How can I efficiently check that `@ProductTypeIds` (which be being translated into `@ProductTypeIds1, @ProductTypeIds2` is all null so I can apply the filter or ignore?

In other words, is there a way to `Distinct` a list of parameters to check if the final result is `null` ?

Thanks

Comment: How are you passing in the `@ProductTypeIds`? What is the type of this variable?

Comment: @Shnugo it's a `List<int>` on C#, being passed to Telerik Reports, where it's a [multivalue nullable parameter](http://docs.telerik.com/reporting/designing-reports-parameters)

Comment: I have no experience with Telerik reports (btw: This is a piece of information you should give in your question...), but I'd suppose this is a declared table variable or a type in SQL Server? Otherwise it could not be used with "logical IN" as the documentation tells... Later to write about `@ProductTypeIds1` (and ...2, ...3) What are they? Well. you've accepted one answer already. However...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea how your tool works, but try the following.

Instead of checking for `null` check for the value that will never come in your params like:

```
WHERE COALESCE(@ProductTypeIds1, @ProductTypeIds2, -666) == -666 OR ...
```

Comment: Excellent! That will work of course, It's so obvious now that I am looking at it! Thank you so much.